# Newly published content gives 404 on wordpress

Tags: php, permalinks

I have an issue with a client website where all new published content gives nothing but a 404 when trying to view it. This applies to posts, pages, and custom post types, yet all previously published content is absolutely fine.

I have tried multiple different things to fix this, with the following results:

- Flush Permalinks: no change
- Change permalinks to default (?id=123): page visible
- reset permalinks to /%postname% : page no longer visible
- set page status to Draft: page visible
- change page url in editor: no change
- delete page and re-add: no change
- add flush permalinks on init (removed quickly! this was just to test): no change
- manually flush permalinks in wp_options: no change
- deactivate Google Content Experiments: no change

I have also taken a fresh copy of the site and duplicated onto one of our test servers in order to continue testing / troubleshooting. However this copy does not have the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas of further steps that could be taken to resolve this?

The site is a legacy site, running on WP 3.2.1. Unfortunately, disabling all plugins is not an option at this point. I do not think it is a plugin issue as the copy worked properly on the duplicate, as stated above.

Comment: If the copy worked fine on the test server then I'd look at server settings, what rights do you have on the .htaccess file? make a copy of it, delete it and see if wp is able to recreate it for now

Comment: I have done this already. It didn't seem to have any effect at all. Which server settings would you suggest checking?

Comment: Apache cache settings ... also check for cache wp plugins

Comment: The server does not run an Apache cache, and there are no cache plugins in use. Running out of ideas here!

Comment: Upgrade wordpress. Version 4 was just released. Version 3.2 is beyond old